# Anonymous threads on embedded systems

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I am new to making threads so I experimented with some code and it seems to work. We have a wpf client interface that connects to an imaging device. We transmit the data from the interface to the central server for storage. I was advised by an external programmer that making an anonymous thread on an embedded system isn't a great idea. But I couldn't figure out why.

Here is a snippet of my code.

```
new Task(() =>
            {
                using (TCPconnector = new TcpClient(App.CT.CTIpAddress, Convert.ToInt32(App.CT.CTIpPort)))
                {
                    try
                    {

                        using (stream = TCPconnector .GetStream())
                        {
                            writer = new BinaryWriter(stream);
                            writer.Write(deviceCT);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Logger.Log.Instance.LogFiles["Client"].Add(ex.ToString(), Logger.Log.Status.Exception);
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        if (stream != null) stream.Close();
                        if (TCPconnector != null) TCPconnector .Close();
                        if (writer != null) writer.Close();
                    }
                }


            }).Start();
```

He said theoretically I can call the functions inline instead of declaring them as the Task method. Since the only reason I'd want to fork if off is if I think the socket calls will take too long and block the current thread (if it is a UI thread). I think it actually will block.

I think that since it is on the UI thread it needs to execute on a background thread. A failed TCP connection can take a very long time (in UI hang time) to time out.

So with that, why is an anonymous thread not a great idea on an embedded system?

Comment: The task (thread) is not functioning on the embedded system (imaging device), it is running on the same machine as the client.

Comment: yes. correct. This code is on the client side. There is code that already interfaces the imaging device to the client computer. This is just an added method to send to the network.

Comment: I was making a statement (not asking a question). What I was saying in a very diplomatic way is that while your external developer may be technically correct, he is incorrect in applying that statement to your code because you are not running an anonymous thread on the imaging device. Or did you already realise that and want to ask about it anyway (making that code block redundant)?

Comment: Thanks @slugster, I misunderstood your first comment. No, I hadn't entirely realized it. Thanks for your guidance. I wanted to ask the community on why they think he would say that about this code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Slugster's comment:

The external developer may be technically correct, he is incorrect in applying that statement to your code because you are not running an anonymous thread on the physical imaging device.

In the long run, the developer and I came to a truce and the code stayed on the client side machine. He was afraid that if it were ever to move onto the imaging device it self (to run standalone) then we would have a problem.

Stepping through the code with VS yielded no problem with this anonymous thread.

Good Luck.